# Opus codec deploy in asterik made unable to call establish

Tags: asterisk, codec, jssip

I was running a asterisk 11.5 with no error. After installed Opus codec with patch in my asterisk

btw i am using browser based sip softphone jssip
Now whenever I am making audio call between 2 peer, no call is getting establish and throwing below errors:

btw i am using browser based sip softphone jssip

```
[Sep 29 09:27:36] WARNING[17065][C-00000003]: sip/sdp_crypto.c:173 sdp_crypto_activate: Could not set SRTP policies
[Sep 29 09:27:36] WARNING[17065][C-00000003]: sip/sdp_crypto.c:173 sdp_crypto_activate: Could not set SRTP policies
[Sep 29 09:27:36] WARNING[17065][C-00000003]: chan_sip.c:11100 process_sdp_a_audio: Got Opus minptime=10
[Sep 29 09:27:36] WARNING[17065][C-00000003]: chan_sip.c:10437 process_sdp: Rejecting secure audio stream without encryption details: audio 17002 RTP/SAVPF 111 103 104 0 8 106 105 13 126



[1000]
secret=test123
context=local
host=dynamic
trustrpid=yes
sendrpid=no
type=friend
qualify=yes
qualifyfreq=600
transport=udp,wss,ws
encryption=yes
dial=SIP/8000
callerid=testuser <8000>
callcounter=yes
avpf=yes
icesupport=yes
directmedia=no
```

Can any one cooperate?

Answer (score 0):

Use `tcpdump` or wireshark to look at the packets, and make sure that they're actually encrypted packets. I looks like it may be rejecting them because it's not SRTP. However, that is only an educated guess. Additionally at the asterisk command line you might want to look at `rtp set debug on`.

You may look to Asterisk 12 for Opus support, where it will be officially supported, or so it seems from the development activity for Asterisk 12.

Here's the [reference to the issue](https://issues.asterisk.org/jira/browse/ASTERISK-21981) and discussion of the fix. And you can see that it's been [approved by the review board here](https://reviewboard.asterisk.org/r/2723/).

I, too, am interested in using Opus. However, without knowing what patch you are using, and the stability of said patch -- it may be difficult (and rather time consuming) to give specific instruction here. I would recommend reporting the issue to the person/group who released the patch as it may help the community project (if it is such).